# Using Bromine to take screenshots when Selenium test fails

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests

I'm new to Bromine and am struggling to find a way to take an automatic screenshot when the test fails. My test case in Bromine is as follows

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "drivers/php");
require_once 'Testing/Selenium.php';
require_once 'Testing/BRUnit.php';

class Example extends BRUnit
{
  function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->selenium->open("/index.php");
    // do some stuff    
    $this->verifyTrue($this->selenium->isTextPresent("Saved"));
  }

}
startTest("Example" , $argv);
?>
```

I've seen that you can do `$this->selenium->captureScreenshotToString()` but dont know how to call this on a failure, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
if (!$this->selenium->isTextPresent("Saved"))
{
    $this->selenium->captureScreenshotToString();
}
```

Comment: I thought there maybe a function that I dont know about that you can define which automatically is called once a test fails so i dont have to write what you wrote for every Assert / Verify function

Comment: Hmmm, don't know much about a selenium. But you could always make a wraper function: `$this->verifyTrueOrScreen(...);`